# Does A warning container class already exist in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a program with a form which connects to a business logic DLL, and of course sometimes there will be "no way to proceed from here" exceptions in the DLL, which I catch and handle as appropriate in the form.

But other times there may be some issue(s) I want to inform the user about that aren't enough to throw a complete wobbly, so what I need is some sort of container/class which the DLL can populate if necessary with one or many warning messages, then pass it back to the form for display in an Info messageBox.

e.g. a multi-issue message:

"The element Fred was in the XML file but not the schema and will not be displayed"

"The element Jane was in the XML file but not the schema and will not be displayed"

"The element Marc was in the XML file but not the schema and will not be displayed"

or a standard one liner:

"You are connected to the FTP server but only with read permissions"

etc.

Is there a pre-existing message class I can use, or can anyone suggest a sensible implementation?

Comment: [List<string>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)? [AggregateException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx)?

Comment: Something like the `ModelStateDictionary`of MVC?

Answer (score 0):

.NET Framework has a [`TraceSource` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource.aspx) for logging purposes. You can use it to log all sorts of messages your program produces. .NET applications can have multiple trace sources; many trace sources already exist in the framework (network, WPF bindings etc.). You can bind a listener to them, filter messages which are important for the user and display them in UI.

If you want to "attach" messages to specific objects, I think there're no ready to use classes. But you can reuse already existing types like [`TraceEventType` enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.traceeventtype.aspx) for severity.